# Save the value into global var during an event to be used for later

Tags: javascript, jquery, global-variables

I'm wondering how to achieve the following functionality please.

I have a global variable which gets assigned a value when a text box receives focus. I want to be able to access this new value outside of the event for later use but obviously with the following implementation the value becomes undefined. Is there a way to overcome this?

```js
var globalVar;

$('.inputIdentifier').on('focus', function() {
  globalVar = $(this).attr('data-val');
  console.log(globalVar);
});

//access the value in globalVar outside the function?
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="inputIdentifier" data-val="myData" />
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `.inputIdentifier` gets assigned to `globalVar` only when it is gets focus. The code below `focus` gets run before the user focus on the input so your `globalVar` will still be undefined. You'll see this from the `console.log` I have added below. Can you call another function inside `focus` and pass `globalVar` as a parameter?

```js
var globalVar;

$('.inputIdentifier').on('focus', function() {
  globalVar = $(this).attr('data-val');
  console.log('globalVar on focus', globalVar);
  doSomething(globalVar);
});

//You will not get the value of $(this).attr('data-val') here. globalVar only gets set when the onFocus of .inputIdentifier
console.log('globalVar on initial run', globalVar);

function doSomething(globalVar){
  console.log('globalVar in doSomething', globalVar);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I did understand why the value was undefined outside but didn't know how to pass it :)

Answer (score 0):

In the code you wrote, it's only has a value if you `'focus'` on input. so until the user don't focus on input, the variable is `undefined`. the problem is only available in the first time that the user never `'focus'` on input Until now.
it's better that use `if statement` or `hasfocus` function for checking it in other function that you use the variable or use initial value for your variable.